# C# optional enum type property setter compiles in classic .net but not in .net core? (cs0019)

Tags: c#, .net, enums, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to port code with this property-setter to .net core. I get an error I didn't expect in this case. Why? What's different?

```
    /// <remarks>This uses the native .NET datatype, rather than the FHIR equivalent</remarks>
    [NotMapped]
    [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
    public Hl7.Fhir.Model.RemittanceOutcome? Outcome
    {
        get { return OutcomeElement != null ? OutcomeElement.Value : null; }
        set
        {
            if(value == null) // CS00019
              OutcomeElement = null; 
            else
              OutcomeElement = new Code<Hl7.Fhir.Model.RemittanceOutcome>(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Outcome");
        }
    }
```

The error is in the setter of an `Enum?` optional type:

```
    CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 
    'RemittanceOutcome?' and '<null>'
```

The type RemittanceOutcome is `public enum RemittanceOutcome`.  Did it become impossible or is the implementation now different, for an optional enum? Am I hitting a compiler bug in ASP.net core 1.0.0 rtm?

This is in a .net core library with a project.json like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.Primitives": "4.1.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.Contracts": "4.0.1",
    "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.11"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [],
    "nowarn": [ "CS3016" ]
  }
}
```

There are a few other surprises porting this code to dnxcore50 (aspnet core 1.0.0 rtm) but this one seems quite enough to chew on for starters.

Sample project: https://github.com/wpostma/fhir-net-api - branch dnxcore50.

Comment: Sounds strange to me. Out of curiosity, will it work if you say `if (!value.HasValue) ...`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or a missing operator overload for `==`. Please fill out an issue here (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) and see what the .NET Core developers say to it.

Comment: I've added an issues on the corefx issue tracker on GitHub. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you've hit a bug. This should be doable. To confirm can you try

```
if(value.HasValue)
```

instead and see if it works?

Comment: that seems to be the Better Way, but what's odd is that the code DOES compile in full .net projects. Is this a compiler bug or is it a *repair* of a compiler bug?

Comment: @WarrenP Wow asking the real questions haha. We can't say for sure unless we talk to the devs probably. I also couldn't find it on the issues list. You can report it there if you want! https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues

Comment: I am going to do a little research and discuss with them.  The code I am porting was generated by a T4 template and so having this special case causes me some grief.

Answer (score 1):

Being a nullable Enum, does checking for HasValue fix the issue?

I.e.

```
/// <remarks>This uses the native .NET datatype, rather than the FHIR equivalent</remarks>
[NotMapped]
[IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
public Hl7.Fhir.Model.RemittanceOutcome? Outcome
{
    get { return OutcomeElement != null ? OutcomeElement.Value : null; }
    set
    {
        if(!value.HasValue)
          OutcomeElement = null; 
        else
          OutcomeElement = new Code<Hl7.Fhir.Model.RemittanceOutcome>(value);
        OnPropertyChanged("Outcome");
    }
}
```